# jhsdb can't attach the java process in MacOS Monterey

Tags: java, jmap

macOS Monterey version is 12.5
and jdk version is 11

I was going with `sudo jhsdb jmap --heap --pid xxxx` to analyze java process. Then I got the error followed

```
Password:
Attaching to process ID 47413, please wait...
ERROR: attach: task_for_pid(47413) failed: '(os/kern) failure' (5)
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process. Could be caused by an incorrect pid or lack of privileges.
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process. Could be caused by an incorrect pid or lack of privileges.
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal$BsdDebuggerLocalWorkerThread.execute(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:169)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal.attach(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:283)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attachDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:672)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebuggerDarwin(HotSpotAgent.java:660)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:342)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:305)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:141)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:185)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JMap.main(JMap.java:176)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.SALauncher.runJMAP(SALauncher.java:369)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.SALauncher.main(SALauncher.java:538)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process. Could be caused by an incorrect pid or lack of privileges.
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal.attach0(Native Method)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal$1AttachTask.doit(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:274)
    at jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal$BsdDebuggerLocalWorkerThread.run(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:144)
```

**I'v tried use jdk14,18,and didn't work out for me.**

so any solution?

Comment: Just to check the obvious, is the PID correct (How are you getting it), and do you have sufficient privilege to attach that process, do you get prompted to enter credentials, or have you done this already before running the command, for example `% su adminUsername`? Please provide details

Comment: yes sir. I got PID from jps command. And also,the java process is still live when i run sudo jhsdb.

Comment: @sorifiend Speak of privilege, I thought that's the key problem, since I already use sudo, I hope it works which didn't.